# Laravel: Should I create custom methods in my model static?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Eloquent provides almost all methods as `static` methods. I need to add my custom methods in model. I wonder should I declare my functions static? What's best in terms of implementation and performance?

Comment: Check out facades http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades

Comment: Not sure why one downvoted it. Thanks anyways

Comment: Probably because it's quite easy to find in the documentation. Nevertheless; you're welcome :)

Comment: Guess one thinks I need to learn about `static` function. I asked in terms of Laravel perspective that what'd be better in terms of implementation and performance.

Comment: Performance; not sure. But facades is definitely the Laravel way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `static` for functions that'll logically be called statically. Read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for details on the difference.

`Model::find()` is static because you don't have an instance of the model yet.

`$model->delete()` is not static because it works on an existing instance of the model.